# View what is currently in Hibernate Second Level Cache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

So I have found sessionFactory.getStatistics() and I can use it for viewing hit and miss counts. But is there an easy way to view what values are actually in the second level cache of hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ehcache, you can use [Ehcache Monitor](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/monitor) or [JMX](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/jmx)